# Sass extend arguments or a workaround

Tags: sass

I am working on a new project that will be in two languages. Arabic and English.

I will be using SASS on this project, and before I start doing any development I want to make sure that I use the best approach regarding the floats and RTL / LTR

I was wondering if it's possible to have arguments to the extend SASS function.

The body of my HTML will have a class depending on the user language. Based on that class, I want to float to the left if EN and right if AR. To do that, I have a quick draft here: http://jsfiddle.net/WJ6wC/

```
.lang-en {
    direction: ltr;
    %float-dir {
        float:left;
    }
    %text-align {
        text-align:left;
    }
}
.lang-ar {
    direction: rtl;
    %float-dir {
        float:right;
    }
    %text-align {
        text-align:right;
    }
}
.content {
    width:500px;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:20px;
    background:#e5e5e5;
    overflow:auto;
    h1, p {
        margin:0;
    }
    .thumbnail {
        @extend %float-dir;
        margin-right:20px;

    }
    .description {
        @extend %float-dir;
        @extend %text-align;
    }
}

.meta {    
      a {

        font-size:12px;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
}

.icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    &:after {
      content:"+";
      display:inline-block;
     }
}

.control-panel {
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    padding:10px 0 0 0;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

There is a jQuery bit that changes the class on click.

Unfortunately, the extent does not accept any arguments from what I know. How can I do so that, depending on the body class to have instead of 'margin-left', 'margin-right' or instead of 'padding-left', 'padding-right'?

I was thinking something like:

```
.content {
     %marginSwap(10px 0 0 10px); 
}
```

and somewhere inside the language class a mixing to swap margin-left value with margin right value.

like a mixin but dependent on the parent class like an extend:

```
@mixin marginSwap($top, $right, $bottom, $left) {
    margin-top:$top;
    margin-right:$left; // Left instead of right
    margin-bottom:$bottom;
    margin-left:$right;
}
```

Hope you understand better from my jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might I recommend taking advantage of the lang attribute?  You could just as easily use mixins instead of extends if you wanted.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/tshuK

```
@mixin margin($v) {
  @if length($v) == 4 {
    margin: $v;

    &:lang(ar) {
      margin: nth($v, 1) nth($v, 4) nth($v, 3) nth($v, 2);
    }
  } @else {
    margin: $v;
  }
}

@mixin margin-right($v) {
  margin-right: $v;

  &:lang(ar) {
    margin-left: $v;
  }
}

:lang(en) {
  direction: ltr;
}

:lang(ar) {
  direction: rtl;
}

%float-left {
  //&:lang(en) {
    float: left;
  //}

  &:lang(ar) {
    float: right;
  }
}

%align-left {
  //&:lang(en) {
    text-align: left;
  //}

  &:lang(ar) {
    text-align: right;
  }
}

.content {
    width:500px;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:20px;
    background:#e5e5e5;
    overflow:auto;
    h1, p {
        margin:0;
    }
    .thumbnail {
        @extend %float-left;
        //@include margin(0 20px 0 0);
        @include margin-right(20px);
    }
    .description {
        @extend %float-left;
        @extend %align-left;
    }
}
```

Instead of using a class, you would set the lang attribute on whatever ancestor element you feel is appropriate (it could be all the way up on the html or body tag if you want).

```
<div lang="en"></div>
```

Comment: That is a good alternative for my Scss, but what about margins & paddings? How would you handle these? Thanks a ton!

Comment: I've added an example for margins

Comment: Awesome! I will do some testing for performance. I wonder how lange a css file for a medium website will be using this technique, rather that creating two separate CSS versions for each language.